# When using TypeScript to check JS via JSDocs, how to declare that a variable corresponds to a namespace?

Tags: javascript, typescript, jsdoc

In my JS code I import a module like so:

```js
const toolbox = require('../toolbox')

/**
 * @param {toolbox.Hammer} hammer
 */
function useHammer(hammer) {
  let nail = new toolbox.Nail()
  hammer.ham(nail)
}
```

Now, because my `tools/index.d.ts` file exports `toolbox` as a namespace. My IDE can see that `hammer` has a method `ham` on it. Awesome! But it cannot see that `toolbox` has a member `Nail` in it.

I tried placing `@module` and `@export` tags in `toolbox/index.js` to no avail. I also tried placing a `@type {toolbox}` over top of the `require` statement but I'm told that `toolbox is referenced directly or indirectly in its own type annotation`.

How can I let my IDE know that `toolbox = require('toolbox')` makes `toolbox` correspond to my namespace?

---

An example `toolbox/index.js` and `toolbox/index.d.ts` for reference:

```js
exports.Hammer = class {
  ham (nail) {
    if (Math.random() > 0.1) {
      exports.nailCount -= 1
      return 'bang!' 
    } else return 'Ouch my thumb!'
  }
}
exports.nailCount = 100
exports.Nail = class {}
```

```js
export = toolbox
export as namespace toolbox

declare namespace toolbox {
  class Nail {}
  class Hammer {
    ham(n: Nail) : string
  }
}
```

and my tsconfig for good measure (since it's a little cargo-culty)

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "checkJs": true,
    "baseUrl": "../",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true
  }
}
```

Comment: I should mention, though it's not essential to this question, that one of my goals is to not modify the JS files at this stage. If this could come entirely from `.d.ts` files that would be excellent. But it's not a show-stopper. Some JSDoc annotations are acceptable at this stage but not preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which IDE are you using?

In **VS Code**, I can see `Nail` and `nailCount` show up as being part of toolbox.

See this image:
[image]

Also, to ensure `hammer.ham` function only accepts a `Nail` instance, add some property to the `Nail` class definition in the `index.d.ts`
E.g.

```
// toolbox/index.d.ts

export = toolbox;
export as namespace toolbox;

declare namespace toolbox {
  class Nail {
    length: string; // new property added
  }
  class Hammer {
    ham(n: Nail): string;
  }
}
```

Now, in `main/index.js` we'll get an error if we pass anything other than a `Nail` instance.
e.g.

```
const toolbox = require("../toolbox");

/**
 * @param {toolbox.Hammer} hammer
 */
function useHammer(hammer) {
  let nail = new toolbox.Nail();
  hammer.ham("nail-string"); // this will show a red squiggle under "nail-string" since it is a string and the compiler expected a Nail instance
}
```

see this image:
[image]

Comment: Hmm, I am using VSCode, maybe there is something about the project structure that is interfering. I'll see if I can reproduce and post back.